# How to use Intellisense from other languages in the current language

Tags: lua, visual-studio-code, gml

I want to use GML's Intellisense in Lua language mode, but I tried multiple methods but they are all invalid.

I also tried to use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), but it only works fine in JavaScript and TypeScript, can't be used for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called vscode-lua that supposedly provides intellisense for the lua language.

Comment: I have known this extension, but when I tried to integrate, the two extensions conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) of a file by clicking on the language indicator in the Status Bar. If you set it to GML, then the GLM's extension's intellisense should kick in

You can also mark all lua files as gml using `files.associations`https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.lua": "gml"
}
```

Comment: I have tried `files.associations`, but it invalidated Lua's highlightings.

Comment: Yeah there's no way to mix and match language features—grabbing highlighting from one language and intellisense for another—at a user level. For that, you'll have to write an extension

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 I could use the Ctrl+, shortcut to navigate from a symbol in an INI file to its definition in a C++ header file. For it to work you need to make sure the header file where the symbol is defined is part of the solution and not just included from a CPP file.